# How to differentiate between Bombus lapidarius and Bombus wurfleini?

Tags: zoology, entomology

I am observing frequently different bumble bees in my garden (Austria prealpine-alpine region). One of them that I frequently saw is all black with red-orange abdomen (tail). From a very simple schematic poster I found I had concluded it would be Bombus *lapidarius*, but now reading a bit more on bumble bees I find it could as well be B. *wurfleini*. My question is now what would be the most obvious/simple way to discern between the two species?